# Custom function to limit excerpt length is returning post title as part of excerpt (WP)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I added the following to functions.php:

```
function excerpt($limit) {
global $id;
  $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
  if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'... <p class="readmore"><a href="'. get_permalink($id) . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( array('echo' => 0, 'before' => 'Permalink to: ', 'after' => '')) . the_title() . '">Read More &#187;</a></p>';
  } else {
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'... <p class="readmore"><a href="'. get_permalink($id) . '" title="' . the_title_attribute( array('echo' => 0, 'before' => 'Permalink to: ', 'after' => '')) . the_title() . '">Read More &#187;</a></p>';
  } 
  $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
  return $excerpt;
}
```

and for some reason it's returning the post title as part of the excerpt (Post title comes first, then excerpt without a space between title & excerpt -- sample here: http://autisticadvocacy.uniongraphics.org/category/news/). Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt)
  . '... <p class="readmore"><a href="'
  . get_permalink($id)
  . '" title="'
  . the_title_attribute(array(
         'echo'   => 0, 
         'before' => 'Permalink to: ', 
         'after' => ''))
  ### change is in this line. (the_title() removed)
  . '">Read More &#187;</a></p>'
  ;
```

The way you write the code it's very hard to read and therefore hard to debug when you run into problems. Try to improve that. A useful function for better formatted strings is [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
$excerpt = sprintf('%s ... <p class="readmode"><a href="%s" title="%s">Read More &#187;</a></p>'
    , implode(" ",$excerpt), get_permalink($id)
    , the_title_attribute(array('echo' => 0, 'before' => 'Permalink to: ', 'after' => ''))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your functions.php file for excerpt and content.

```
<?php
// Custom Excerpt 
function excerpt($limit) {
$excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
array_pop($excerpt);
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
} else {
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
} 
$excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
return $excerpt;
}

// Content Limit 
function content($limit) {
$content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
if (count($content)>=$limit) {
array_pop($content);
$content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
} else {
$content = implode(" ",$content);
} 
$content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
return $content;
}
?>
```

Now, instead of using the_content() or the_excerpt in your loop, use excerpt($limit) or content($limit).

If you want to limit your excerpt to 300 words the code would look like this:

```
<?php echo excerpt(50); ?>
<?php echo content(300); ?>
```

I got another way to display limited excerpt by character. Here is the functions.php file code.

```
function get_excerpt(){
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 100);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
$excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
$excerpt = $excerpt.'... <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">Read More</a>';
return $excerpt;
}
```

After this you need to add where you want to display your customized character by character.

```
<?php echo get_excerpt(); ?>
```

Source: http://www.e2soft.com/blog/custom-excerpt-and-content-limit-wordpress/